# How to mirror an animation with out the naming convention?

Tags: animation, bones

So I have a rig set up in Blender that I got from a game for example, but the bones do not follow the usual naming conventions to allow them to be flipped or mirrored normally in Blender. Is there a way to do it regardless of bone names? or Is there a script or anything that could just rename bone to one thing and rename them back? I know this is an odd question, but I have no idea how to do this without wasting time renaming things back and forth.

Comment: script shouldn't be too hard as long as the bone names follow some logic. How are they named?

Comment: For example, the bones are named b_L_Arm1 or b_R_Arm2 for example.

Comment: Does the program you export to care about the names?

Comment: Yes, it does. The names have to be relative in order to work.

Comment: relative to what? Can you try to rename 2 bones manually, do something, name it back and export? If that works I can write you a script that does that for all bones

Comment: Well yes, that works, I even tried that just now actually.